# What is this sentense structure 'If you had ....., I would have been .........'

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect

I came across this sentence on stack exchange and it confused me.

> 'If you had called me 10 minutes ago, I would have been sleeping.' on

What is the structure of the above sentence called?

Why 'If you **had** called me? Can it be replaced with 'If you called me?'

I thought 'had called' is past perfect which means it happened before another event in the past. But in this case, it sounds like 'sleeping' came before.

Answer (score 0):

This is **third conditional**.

We make the third conditional by using the past perfect after 'if' and then 'would have' and the past participle in the second part of the sentence:

It talks about the past. It's used to describe a situation that didn't happen, and to imagine the result of this situation.

> 1)If she had studied, she would have passed the exam (but, really we know she didn't study and so she didn't pass)
>
> 2)If I hadn't eaten so much, I wouldn't have felt sick (but I did eat a lot, and so I did feel sick).
>
> 3)If you had called me 10 minutes ago, I would have been sleeping.' (that means you didn't call me 10 minutes ago but if you had done that, I wouldn't have answered because I was asleep)

Comment: Thank you so much. I've always been confused with all these English tenses and how to apply them.